# #define __attribute__((always_inline)) evaluation in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have this Macro:

`#define INLINE __attribute((always_inline)) inline`

and I want it to turn this:

```
INLINE void DoStuff() {

}
```

into this:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void DoStuff() {

}
```

But I am getting this error upon compilation: "declaration does not declare anything" in the macro's expansion. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The preprocessor does text substitution, exactly as you are trying to do.   It doesn't "evaluate" macros.   Rather than force people to guess what you are doing wrong, try (1)  providing actual code that exhibits the problem, in the form of a [mcve] that OTHER people can use to get the same behaviour   (2)  include the error messages in your question.

Comment: What is `__attribute` and `always_inline` ? how you define them ?

Comment: @Landstalker sorry I meant __attribute__ from gcc. Edited.

Comment: In this case, you should edit this alos `#define INLINE __attribute((always_inline)) inline` in your post to this : `#define INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline`

Comment: You're still building in your preconceptions.  I seriously doubt you'll get the error "declaration does not declare anything" if you compile with the -E -P flags (i.e., "in the macro's expansion"), since the preprocessor has no concept of declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the correct way for the gcc family compilers

```
#define INLINE inline __attribute__((always_inline))

int INLINE add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}


int main()
{
    printf("%d", add(rand(), rand()));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/BM6Wjw

Comment: This is exactly what was causing my compiler to send an error. Problem solved! I have always seen programmers declare the inline attribute incorrectly, where it is placed before the type, even on some of the top search results in google. Seems some installations are a little more lax but my compiler configuration is not.

Comment: It should not make a difference where one places the `inline` keyword.  It should work when placed either before or after the type.  FYI -- the docs for gcc, show the `inline` keyword being placed BEFORE the type. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html